# Markov Decision Process - Optimal policy invariance to scaling in the Utility Function

Tags: markov-process, artificial-intelligence, utility

The title says it all. If i use a discounted Utility Function, why is the optimal policy invariant with respect tot the scaling of the Utility Function by a positive Factor?

Answer (score 1):

Let $u$ be your utility function and $\alpha>0$, and $\delta\in(0,1)$ the discount factor.

Let's start with deterministic processes. You want to have a process $(x_n^*)$ that gives higher discounted utility than all other paths $(x_n)$: $$\sum_n \delta^n u(x_n^*)\geq\sum_n \delta^n u(x_n^*).$$
This is clearly equivalent to  $$\alpha\sum_n \delta^n u(x_n^*)\geq\alpha\sum_n \delta^n u(x_n^*)$$
$$\sum_n \delta^n \alpha u(x_n^*)\geq\sum_n \delta^n \alpha u(x_n^*).$$
So the optimal policy does  not change. Since expectation is again linear, a similar argument can be made for the stochastic case.